# Using if, elif, else in List Comprehensions, Python

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I created the following list comprehension in python:

```
[int(a[0].internal_value).lower() if type(a[0].internal_value) in (str,unicode) and a[0].internal_value.isdigit() == True
 else str(a[0].internal_value).lower() if type(a[0].internal_value) in (str,unicode)
 else int(a[0].internal_value) if type(a[0].internal_value) in (float,int)
 for a in ws.iter_rows() if a[0].internal_value <> None]
```

I'm having issues trying to construct the final else, if condition:

```
else int(a[0].internal_value) if type(a[0].internal_value) in (float,int)
```

I get an invalid syntax if I use the if conditional in that line.

```
 if type(a[0].internal_value) in (float,int)
```

If I remove the if statement

```
else int(a[0].internal_value)
```

then it seems to run fine. I need to have that if statement in there.

To me the else, if conditions are list comprehensions way of doing the more simple if, else conditions:

```
if i == x:
  do something
elif i == y:
  do something
elif i == z:
  do something
```

By rule, you do not always have to have an 'else' to close a series of conditional sentences. It seems to me, that my code wants a final 'else' in the comprehension. Am I correct in stating that and if so, is there a way to construct a final else, if in a python list comprehension instead of a final else?

Comment: Note: `<>` has been deprecated in favour of `!=`; the deprecated operator has been removed from Python 3 altogether.

Comment: @Martijn. I'm running 2.7

Comment: @Joran Beasley. You need to start somewhere with list comprehensions.

Comment: @Mike, starting is `[ x*x for x in range(10) ]`, not this.  Listen to Joran...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are (ab)using [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), and they **must** be of the form `true_expression if test else false_expression`. These expressions *always* produce a value, unlike an `if` compound statement.

Note that you should *not* test for `== True`; boolean expressions are already true or false without that test. Don't use `<>` either, that operator has been deprecated and has removed from Python 3 altogether. When testing for `None`, a singleton, you'd use `is not None` however.

You are testing against `type()` results; that looks like you want to use [`isinstance()` tests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead.

You are also using `int()` on values, then calling `.lower()` on the result. There is no `int.lower()` method, so those calls will fail with an `AttributeError`.

The following is closer to working just fine, unless there are more types than `int`, `float`, `str` or `unicode`:

```
[int(a[0].internal_value) if isinstance(a[0].internal_value, (float, int)) or a[0].internal_value.isdigit() 
 else str(a[0].internal_value).lower()
 for a in ws.iter_rows() if a[0].internal_value is not None]
```

However, I'd farm out the conversion to filter function instead:

```
def conversion(value):
    if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
        return int(value)
    return str(value).lower()
```

then use *that* in a list comprehension:

```
[conversion(a[0].internal_value) for a in ws.iter_rows() if a[0].internal_value is not None]
```

Comment: yeah (I gave you +1 all the same) since that was a very good explanation if you actually for some reason wanted to do a list comprehension like that :P

Comment: @Martijn. Thanks for taking the time to work me through this. I'm using your code and doing some testing. I'll get back and let you know my results. Thanks!

Comment: @Martijn. Thanks that worked! I may have some more types to script around, but I think I can handle that in the function and call to the list comprehension. Very nice clear and concise answer!

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier if you create an auxilary function to help you. I also removed `== True` and `int().lower()`. I don't think there's any benefit to cramming all the logic into the list comprehension, but that's up to you.

```
def helper(x):
    if type(x) in (str,unicode) and x.isdigit():
        return int(x)
    elif type(x) in (str,unicode):
        return str(x).lower()
    elif type(x) in (float,int):
        return int(x)

[helper(a[0].internal_value)
 for a in ws.iter_rows()
 if a[0].internal_value <> None]
```

Comment: @axblount. Thanks for that! Definitely resolves me problem and helps me understand when to properly use list comprehensions. I'm on a bit of a learning curve right now :)