# way of ignoring None elements in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, nonetype

sample code

```
list = [i.get('content').encode('utf-8') for i in self.soup.find_all('meta',attrs={"name": "description"})]
```

The problem is that `.encode('utf-8')` will raise an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

if one of the elements of the list is `None`.

I am wondering if there is a 'pythonic' way of keeping it in one line and ignoring None elements. For example can you put a `if not None` clause in the list? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would break this up into a generator expression for the initial fetching to limit the lookup, so `get` is only called once for performance.

```
items_i = (i.get('content') for i in self.soup.find_all('meta',attrs={"name": "description"}))
items = [i.encode('utf-8') for i in items_i if i]
```

Comment: excellent suggestion I was just editing my answer to add a generator expression

Comment: Thanks, I will look up generator expressions as performance will likely be an issue. I'd also be able to move the `encode` line to a method so it can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

you can give `.get` a default argument to use instead of None

```
[i.get('content','').encode('utf-8') for i in self.soup.find_all('meta',attrs={"name": "description"})]
```

or you can filter it out

```
[i.get('content').encode('utf-8') for i in self.soup.find_all('meta',attrs={"name": "description"}) if i.get('content') is not None]
```

you should note that its not `i` that is none but rather its 'content'

Comment: thanks, that worked, I think I will filter it out, because adding a default argument will leave the blank '' element in the list.

Comment: i found the solution a few minutes after writing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459744/using-if-elif-else-in-list-comprehensions-python formulating questions on stackoverflow == my version of rubber duck debugging. :)